# Cython Installation Problems

Tags: python, installation, pip, cython

First I downloaded the .whl file for Cython from the pythonlibs website, then I open up my bash terminal and execute the following command:

```
 python install Cython
```

here is the output:

```
unable to execute 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc': No such file or directory

error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools,
```

If it helps, my operating system is windows 10, thanks

Comment: `apt-get install python-dev`?

Comment: There is a wiki that helps  [link](https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/InstallingOnWindows) you install cython on windows. This might help you Also to the commentor above apt-get is not for windows.

Comment: @ZainPatel `apt-get` on Windows?

Comment: @phd "then I open up my bash terminal" I presume they're either using a bash emulator or WSL. Note the output has "/usr/bin" which isn't the Windows Filesystem.

Comment: I am using unbuntu bash on windows